# Is a following function periodic $f(x) =\tan x +\tan (\sqrt{2}x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Motivated with [$\cos(x)+\cos(x\sqrt{2})$ is not periodic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390280/cosx-cosx-sqrt2-is-not-periodic) I found this question interesting:

Is a following function periodic $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $$f(x) =\tan x +\tan (x\sqrt{2})$$

The approach in that link can not help. Any ideas? Also from a graph I draw in Geogebra I can not rule out it is not periodic.

Comment: Perhaps you should show (using the minimum) that $f'$ is not periodic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to show that a differentiable function $f$ is periodic only if $f'$ is periodic.

So

$$f'(x)=1+\tan^2(x)+\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2\tan^2(\sqrt 2 x)$$

If $f'$ has a period $T>0$ then

$$1+\sqrt 2=1+\tan^2(T)+\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2\tan^2(\sqrt 2T)$$

This implies that $\tan T$ and $\tan(\sqrt 2 T)$ are both $0$, which is impossible for the same reason as for $\cos$.

Comment: The “if” part isn't quite true (it requires that the integral of $f'$ over one period is zero), but “only if” is true, which is all you need in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about functions defined over $\Bbb R$, which is not the case. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$\tan(x)$ has period $\pi$ and $\tan(\sqrt2 x)$ has period $\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$. How to display a period of $\tan(x)+\tan(\sqrt2 x)$ with the irrational $\sqrt2$ in place? You need for this two integers $n,m$ such that $$n\pi=\dfrac{m\pi}{\sqrt2}$$